# flutter bluetooth issue on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, flutter, bluetooth

I face a problem when using `flutter blue plugin` (0.5.0 version).

My Bluetooth device is connected only once and I can't connect another time until I close the Bluetooth on my iPhone and turn it on again.

this is a video for the experiment.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pQW4JFQI5R_zcxF3wfozT6Ru2AY2KxBm/view?usp=sharing

I can't use the latest plugin version because the project is old.
this issue happened in ios only.

this is my connection code:

```
_connect(BluetoothDevice d) async {
device = d;
// Connect to device
deviceConnection = _flutterBlue
    .connect(device, timeout: const Duration(seconds: 4))
    .listen(
  null,
  onDone: _disconnect,
);

// Update the connection state immediately
device.state.then((s) {
  setState(() {
    deviceState = s;
  });
});

// Subscribe to connection changes
deviceStateSubscription = device.onStateChanged().listen((s) {
  if (mounted)
    setState(() {
      deviceState = s;
    });
  if (s == BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
    device.discoverServices().then((s) {
      var bservice = s
          .where((r) =>
          r.uuid
              .toString()
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains("0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))
          .first;
      if (bservice != null) {
        var char = bservice.characteristics
            .where((c) =>
            c.uuid
                .toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains("0000ffe4-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))
            .first;
        if (char != null) {
          _setNotification(char);
        }
      }
      bservice = s
          .where((r) =>
          r.uuid
              .toString()
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains("00001808-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))
          .first;
      if (bservice != null) {
        var char = bservice.characteristics
            .where((c) =>
            c.uuid
                .toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains("00002a18-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))
            .first;
        if (char != null) {
          _setNotification(char);
        }
      }

      setState(() {
        //Accu-Answer isaw Service UUID="0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
        //Accu-Answer isaw Characteristics UUID="0000ffe4-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
        //YASEE Service UUID="00001808-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
        //YASEE Characteristics UUID="00002a18-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

        // var bservice=s.where((r) =>r.uuid.toString().toLowerCase().contains("0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")).first;//Accu-Answer
        // var bservice=s.where((r) =>r.uuid.toString().toLowerCase().contains("00001808-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")).first;//YASEE
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          var bservice = s[i];
          var tmpUUID = bservice.uuid.toString().toLowerCase();

          if (tmpUUID == "0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb") {
            var char = bservice.characteristics
                .where((c) =>
                c.uuid
                    .toString()
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .contains("0000ffe4-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))
                .first;
            if (char != null) {
              _setNotification(char);
            }
            break;
          } else if (tmpUUID == "00001808-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb") {
            var char = bservice.characteristics
                .where((c) =>
                c.uuid
                    .toString()
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .contains("00002a18-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))
                .first;
            if (char != null) {
              _setNotification(char);
            }
            break;
          }
        }

        //services = s;
      });
    });
  }
});}
```

I'm testing on `iPhone 6` plus ios version `12.4.7`

Comment: What exactly does not work? I don't exactly know how to help you.

Answer (score 4):

I had many problems with flutter blue lib and decided to try another library and my problems were gone. It should be no problem to transfer the code. The API is a bit different but the examples are good and solid.

This is the package I used and I can highly recommend it: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ble_lib